align widgets across columns with flutter
How can I achieve a view like below?
The part that I am interested in is the part with the time line. Basically I want the following:
16:03.  origin icon   Barbarossaplatz
             |
             |
             |
             |
        place icon    Efferen

I want the icon to be aligned with the location on the right side of it.
Then height of the line between the icons is variable based upon how many lines the location has.


It is about aligning the icons with the corresponding text on the right

You can use Stepper Widget for this.

@NipulRathod I just tried Stepper, but I would need to customize a lot. Replace the default icons, disable the callback functions etc. But visually it looks fine.

I have used timeline_tile and that is pretty much what I was looking for.
